# How to access a cli class in c++?

Tags: c++, crystal-reports, command-line-interface

I need to make a new object of a cli class in plain C++ code.

I am new to cli, please help

my cli class:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace CrystalDecisions::Shared;
using namespace CrystalDecisions::CrystalReports::Engine;
using namespace CrystalDecisions::Windows::Forms;

namespace  CrystalRapport {
    // This is the main form that will hold the viewer control.  
    ref class ViewForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private:
        //Declare the Viewer Control, Report Document, and other
        //objects needed to set the connection information.
    public:
        ViewForm()..
        void InitForm()..
        //This function initializes the form and adds the viewer to the form.
        void ViewForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)..
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`gcnew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you want to create .NET object in CLI C++.

Comment: Not necessarily. An automatic variable is generally preferable.

Comment: thanks for your answer. gcnew requires Compiler option: /clr. I need to call my cli class from MainWindow.cpp to load the report. 
/**
Loads the report dialog
*/
void MainWindow::on_action_Report_triggered()
{ }

Comment: You need to enable /clr option to create .NET objects in your c++ code.

Comment: thanks for your help. You are right, my cli class (cpp) is using /clr. But my mainWindow.cpp is not using /clr. How to access my cli class ViewForm from mainwindow.cpp ?

Comment: I assume you have `MainWindow` and `ViewForm` in different projects since you have different /clr option values for them. You can access CLI class from non-CLI class freely, and vice-versa. You should encapsulate any .NET calls in CLI-class, that's what they are for.

Comment: You are right. I have different projects. "You can access CLI class from non-CLI class freely"  Yes this is exacly what I need to do. My first question was maybe not clear. English is not my first language. Please help me with some code examples.

Comment: Maybe I was to in a hurry. Calling native from CLI is straightforward. Calling CLI from native may be a little trickier. Try to google on the latter. Use `marshal` and `PInvoke` keywords.

Comment: I found an easy example on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10020/Using-managed-code-in-an-unmanaged-application thanks

Comment: @Mikhail In fact not using the infamous `PInvoke` is one of the main reasons for using C++/CLI in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
ref class Student
{
    ...
};

...

Student^ student = gcnew Student();
student->SelectSubject("Math", 97);
```

Ref:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17787/C-CLI-in-Action-Instantiating-CLI-classes

Answer (score 0):

I found an example. Use .NET Assemblies in Native C++ Applications

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb892742.aspx

If you create a C# Crystal Reports project you can use this example.
(with some changes)

Comment: Maybe you could add a little explanation of what C# Crystal Reports are, and how they work in general.